# HTML5 pattern matching

Tags: regex, html

Is it possible to make some kind of pattern matching with html5 to only allow 3-digit numbers to a *text* form. I do not want the input type to be *number* because I dont like the visual design of it.

The closest I get is `pattern=".{0.3}"` But that accepts all kind of text input - not limited to numbers.

```
<input type="text" name="price" id="price" pattern="fancy code here">
```

Question: Can you make a pattern in input type="text" that accepts only integers in the max length of 3?

Comment: If `pattern` accepts regexes, how about just `pattern="\d{3}"`?

Comment: Great, pattern="\d{0,3}" was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: My regex does not allow empty strings, hence the `{3}` criteria. Your regex accepts digits of length 0, 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: Use `\d{1,3}` to accept digits of length 1-3.

Comment: Yeah but if i leave it empty as null I can still send that data. I want like a not null check within the regex.

Its a form that sends to a database.

Comment: The required="required" sorted that out!

Comment: you maybe need the \d{1,3} regexp and the "required" attribute one your html element

Comment: Yeah I have both. Working.

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

```
\d{1,3}
```

and the *required* attribute